# What's this number under "power capabilities" in "power data" for a device?

Tags: windows-7, power-management, device-manager

I would like to understand what the number 00000009 means in the picture. I mean, I understand that the things under it can say all kind of thins about power capabilities, and I've even been able to google some of them. But I haven't been able to find out what the numeric value means, why it's there or how to read it

In English, it's device properties->details->power data->power capabilites.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is that the values you see there will map to values in the Windows header files, which you can examine on MSDN, if you know what you are looking for.

I expect that the 0x9 value is actually a bitmask of boolean values, stating that the device is capable of doing the think associated with value 0x1 and the thing associated with value 0x8.

I would imagine that some of these values will marry up with the values reported by WMI, too (specifically the CIM_LogicalDevice class) -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx has more on this.

Of course, all this depend on why this particular number is important to you in the first place?

I could guess, but then I might be inclined to suggest that you shouldn't try to parse the values directly from the device manager, but rather use programming interfaces such as WMI to query the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way for Windows to determine what Power Capabilities the device has. For example, your monitor may be able to enter sleep mode / hibernation. Because of this, the monitor will have a different power capability than, say, your mouse.

The power capabilities are just a flag for the operating system to say "Hey, look! This monitor can be turned off when we go into sleep mode, lets do it!"

Comment: Thank you. Could you please see the edited question?

Comment: I see what you mean. All I can see is that it is a hexadecimal flag used to represent the supported power states of the device. Unfortunately, I believe windows calculates this based off of the supported power modes listed in the device's driver.